# dimension of a subspace of matrix space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the linear space of $n\times n$ matrix over some field $F$. Let $W$ be a subspace. $\forall A,B\in W$ we have $AB\in W$. And $\dim W>1$. Every non-zero matrix in $W$ is invertible. Prove that $ \dim W$ is even.

Comment: Are you stuck somewhere? Did you try proceeding by contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer, but this seems relevant: $W$ must be a skew-field.

Fix non-zero $B \in W$. Then the map $\phi_B : A \mapsto BA$ is linear and invertible on $V$. Restricting this map to $W$, certainly $\phi_B|_W$ is injective, and hence it must be surjective as it is a linear operator on the finite-dimensional space $W$.

Note also that $\phi_B^{-1}(A) = B^{-1}A$. Since $\phi_B^{-1}|_W = (\phi_B|_W)^{-1}$, it follows that $B^{-1} B = I \in W$. Moreover, $\phi_B^{-1}(I) = B^{-1} \in W$, hence $W \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is a group. Already $W$ is an additive group, and matrix multiplication satisfies the distributive laws. Thus, $W$ is a skew-field.

In a previous edit, I said it must be a field, but of course, I didn't verify commutativity of the multiplication.

Comment: I defined $\phi_B$ on $V$. Since it's multiplication by an invertible matrix, it has an inverse $A \mapsto B^{-1}A$. This makes it invertible. The map $\phi_B|_W$ is therefore injective. However, $\phi_B|_W$ maps into $W$, and $W$ is a finite-dimensional space. That makes $\phi_B|_W$ an injective operator on a finite-dimensional space. There is a theorem that says it must be surjective (one way to prove it: injective operators preserve linear independence, so it maps a basis for $W$ to a linearly independent set of the appropriate size, which must be a basis).

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah because in a finite dimension space, if a linear map is injective then it's surjective

Comment: Yes, I should note that I can see that now, it's just I am getting a strange result from it. Then if $A,B \in W \setminus {0}$, then $AB \in W$, and by $\phi^{-1}$, $B^{-1}AB \in W$? Doesn't that make that a normal subgroup? Then we can split $V'$, the group of invertible matrices, into cosets. The vector space $V' + \{\mathbf{0}\}$ can then be split into subspaces. Why? If $B$ is a basis for $W$, then $MB$ is a basis for $MW$. (pardon my notation). Then $\dim W \mid \dim( {V' + \{\mathbf{0}\}}) = n^2$ , but if we make n odd, then the claim is false
Ik i'm wrong, I'm a bit tired but idk where

Comment: Thank you. To continue your idea i looked up and found out for $F=R$ we can use Frobenius theorem of real division algebra. The theorem states there are only two such skew fields and they are indeed even dimensions. I think the question should be $F=R$. For other fields such as $F=Q$ it's wrong.

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah If you want to prove $W$ is a normal subgroup (of, I guess, the group of invertible $n \times n$ matrices over $F$), you would have to show $B^{-1} A B \in W$ for all invertible $B$, not just $B \in W$. The fact that $B^{-1} A B \in W$ whenever $A, B \in W \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is a consequence of the closure of $W$ under multiplication and inversion.

Comment: Ah yes, stupid me at it again... thanks!